Short exact sequences of vector spaces and additivity of trace
My confusion arises from a proof that I read that the Lefschetz number of a map $f:X \to X$, defined as
$$
L(f) = \sum_{i \geq 0} (-1)^i \mathrm{tr}(f_*: H_i(X; \mathbb Q) \to H_i(X; \mathbb Q)),
$$
can be computed directly from the chain groups of $X$ (as opposed to its homology groups, as in the definition). Here are the notes I'm using. The author proves the following lemma:

Lemma. Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space and $W \leq V$ a subspace. Let $A: V\to V$ be a linear map such that $A(W) \subset W$. Let $B = A|_W: W \to W$ and $C: V/W \to V/W$ the induced map on the quotient. Then
$$
\mathrm{tr} (A) = \mathrm{tr} (B) + \mathrm{tr} (C).
$$

Then he gives a proof of the following result, which is supposed to be a corollary:

Corollary. Let $f_{\bullet}: C_{\bullet}(K; \mathbb Q) \to C_{\bullet}(K; \mathbb Q)$ be a chain map. Then
$$
\sum_{i \geq 0} (-1)^i \mathrm{tr}(f_i: C_i(K) \to C_i(K)) = \sum_{i \geq 0} (-1)^i \mathrm{tr}(f_*: H_i(K) \to H_i(K)),
$$
with homology groups understood to be over $\mathbb Q$.


Proof. There is an exact sequence
$$
0 \longrightarrow B_i(K; \mathbb Q) \longrightarrow Z_i(K; \mathbb Q) \longrightarrow H_i(K; \mathbb Q) \longrightarrow 0.
$$
This is since $H_i(K, \mathbb Q)$ is defined as the quotient of $Z_i$ over $B_i$. We also have the exact sequence
$$
0 \longrightarrow Z_i(K; \mathbb Q) \longrightarrow C_i(K; \mathbb Q) \longrightarrow B_{i - 1}(K; \mathbb Q) \longrightarrow 0.
$$
This is true by definition of $B_{i - 1}$ and $Z_i$. Let $f_i^H, f_i^B, f_i^Z, f_i^C$ be the various maps induced by $f$ on the corresponding groups. Then we have
\begin{align*}
L(|f|) &= \sum_{i \geq 0} (-1)^i \mathrm{tr}(f_i^H)\\
&= \sum_{i \geq 0} (-1)^i (\mathrm{tr}(f_i^Z) - \mathrm{tr}(f_i^B))\\
&= \sum_{i \geq 0} (-1)^i (\mathrm{tr}(f_i^C) - \mathrm{tr}(f_{i - 1}^B) - \mathrm{tr}(f_i^B)).
\end{align*}
Because of the alternating signs in dimension, each $f_i^B$ appears twice in the sum with opposite signs. So all $f_i^B$ cancel out, and we are left with
$$
L(|f|) = \sum_{i \geq 0} (-1)^i \mathrm{tr} (f_i^C).
$$

I'm confused as to why the exact sequences are there, though I can see that the two steps of the trace calculation seem to use them. If this is supposed to be a corollary of the lemma, shouldn't we be trying to prove that $f_i(B_i) \subset B_i$ and $f_i(Z_i) \subset Z_i$? I saw in another post that for a short exact sequence of finite abelian groups
$$
0 \longrightarrow A \longrightarrow B \longrightarrow C \longrightarrow 0,
$$
we can obtain
$$
\mathrm{rank}(B) = \mathrm{rank}(A) + \mathrm{rank}(C).
$$
This seems related (except that the sequences in the proof above involve $\mathbb Q$-vector spaces, not just $\mathbb Z$-modules), but I can't quite work out how everything fits together.

Do you know that a s.e.s. $0 \to A \to B \to C \to 0$ gives rise to an isomorphism $B / A \cong C$? Also, it stands to reason that you should already know that $f_i(B_i) \subseteq B_i$ and $f_i(Z_i) \subseteq Z_i$: This is a basic property of chain maps.

The lemma is applied twice. Once in concluding $t(f^H)=t(f^Z)-t(f^B)$ and once in concluding $t(f^Z)=t(f^C)-t(f^{B[-1]})$

@BenSteffan Yes I see, the isomorphism is clear from the first isomorphism theorem. So we're using the exact sequence to get the respective $C$'s into the quotient form in the lemma, then applying the basic properties (which I forgot about). Thanks!
